# MobileConnect Attributes in Email Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have mobileconnect demographics custom attributes that I want to be able to use the data in for email sends.  How can I do this in Marketing Cloud?  Extract, query, API calls?  I realize we have the views but how do I get the custom attribute data?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use queries, just add them to the list of the columns to pull.

For example, let's assume you have a custom attribute called `LastOrderID` added in MobileConnect. You can retrieve it with the following query:

```
Select
    _ContactID as ContactID,
    LastOrderID
From
    _MobileAddress
```

Default MobileConnect attributes have the underscore (`_`) prefix and require aliases to be put into data extensions, but custom attribute names remain as you created them and have no prefix.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!